# transaction.autocommit in django 1.7

Tags: mysql, django, transactions

Can someone please tell me what does transaction.autocommit() do?

What is the difference between the following code snippets?

```
model_object.save()
```

```
with transaction.autocommit():
     model_object.save()
```

```
with transaction.autocommit():
     model_object.save()

        with transaction.autocommit():
             model2_object.save()

     model3_object.save()
```

Also, do we need transaction.autocommit() in Django 1.7? As long as I understand Django does db operations in autocommit mode only. Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Django’s default behavior is to run in autocommit mode. Each query is immediately committed to the database, unless a transaction is active.
This means if in a view function there are 2 delete operation and one update then will run one by one and if the last one failed the two fist operation is done to database.

To activate transaction decorate view function with

```
@transaction.atomic
```

In this mode before any database operation (update, delete, insert) django will start a transaction and when everything goes right then transaction will be `commited`, otherwise will be `rollbacked`.

Consider the piece of code below:

```
from django.db import transaction

def viewfunc(request):
    # This code executes in autocommit mode (Django's default).
    do_stuff()

    with transaction.atomic():
        # This code executes inside a transaction.
        do_more_stuff()
```

The code above is another way to do some part of the view statements in autocommit and the rest embraces inside `with transaction.atomic()`  in transaction mode.

The code below will do reverse:

```
@transaction.atomic
def viewfunc(request):
    # This code executes in transactional mode
    do_stuff()

    with transaction.autocommit():
        # This code executes in autocommit mode (Django's default).
        do_more_stuff()
```

`do_stuff()` will run in transactionl and `do_more_stuff()` in autocommit mode

refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/transactions/

Comment: so If I write with transaction.autocommit: model_obj.save(), it is same as model_obj.save()?

Comment: If there is no attomic decorator on your function I consider yes